# select radio button in selenium using python

Tags: selenium, radio-button

I tried
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='option1']")`.click

But Error message generated

**Note:**

1. value attributes is not supported by find_element
2. ID is not available as an attribute

Below is the HTML code

```
label _ngcontent-c12="" class="custom-control custom-radio"

input _ngcontent-c12="" class="custom-control-input input-md input-rectangle ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched"  formcontrolname="radioBtns" name="radioBtns" nbinput="" type="radio" value="option1"

span _ngcontent-c12="" class="custom-control-description">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `find_element_by_css_selector` function.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='option1']").click()
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: Error message generated:

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid input-md input-rectangle" formcontrolname="radioBtns" name="radioBtns" nbinput="" type="radio" value="option1"> is not clickable at point (491, 322). Other element would receive the click: <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)